# Dynamic MKOverlay changing its boundingMapRect

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkoverlay

Is it possible to have a `MKOverlay` that can change its bounds over time? The `boundingMapRect` property is used to define its bounding box. The `boundingMapRect` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MKOverlay/boundingMapRect) states (emphasis added):

> Implementers of this protocol must set this area when implementing their overlay class, and **after setting it, you must not change it**.

I suspect MapKit's overlay engine uses boundingMapRect to build a spatial index of the overlays. I wonder if there's a way to trigger a reindex. I really don't want to have to remove then re-add.

**Edit**: Apple's own [Breadcrumb example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html) simply sets the boundingMapRect to `MKMapRectWorld`. This seem inefficient as the renderer will be called anywhere in the entire world region.